# IE take 302 response, but ignore it

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, post, redirect

We use jquery/ajax for sending some data to the server (post method). And take 302 redirect as a response. 
But nothing happend. I mean, we see "302 found" in IE dev tool and new location, but browser ignoring it and stay on the same page. 
Can you give some advice for us? 
In other browser, such as FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera redirect works normal.

UPD: problem solved. in location was http link, but we work above https. I think that IE doesn't like it. When we change location link to https, all begin to work.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254219/jquery-ajax-request-302-redirect-what-callbacks-are-available

Comment: thx for your comment, but we don't use crossdomain redirect. we read all topic very attentive - sad, it's not for us.